# Unique values of powers of complex roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

*Problem*: Show that

$$\left(\sqrt[n]{z}\right)^m$$

has exactly $n / (n, m) $ unique values, where $(n, m)$ is the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$.
($n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, $z$ is complex number).

*My efforts to solve it*: Using the root formula we have:
$$\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{|z|}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\varphi + 2\pi k}{n}\right) + i\sin{\left(\frac{\varphi + 2\pi k}{n}\right)}\right)$$
where $$\varphi = Arg(z), \ \ \ k = 0,\ldots, n-1$$

then using Moivre's formula and omitting the $\sqrt[n]{|z|}$ (since number of roots does not depend on it) we get that arguments of $\left(\sqrt[n]{z}\right)^m$ are:
$$(\varphi + 2\pi k)\frac{m}{n}, \ \ \ k = 0,\ldots, n-1$$
For simplicity, let us set $\varphi = 0$, so we have

$$2\pi k \frac{m}{n}, \ \ \ k = 0,\ldots, n-1$$

We see (it's obvious to me from the examples below, but still I would like to clearly prove it) that if the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ is irreducible (i.e. $m$ and $n$ are co-prime), then we will get exactly $n$ unique values on unit circle. But if $\frac{m}{n}$ is reducible, we only have $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, m)}$ unique values.

**Example 1** ($m = 2, n = 3$).

So the arguments of $\left(\sqrt[3]{z}\right)^2$ are

$$0, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{8\pi}{3}$$
and number of unique values = $\frac{3}{\gcd(3, 2)} = 3$

**Example 2** ($m = 5, n = 6$). Arguments of $\left(\sqrt[6]{z}\right)^5$ are
$$0, \frac{5\pi}{3}, \frac{10\pi}{3}, 5\pi, \frac{20\pi}{3}, \frac{25\pi}{3}$$
and number of unique values = $\frac{6}{\gcd(6, 5)} = 6$

**Example 3** (reducible fraction) ($m = 4, n = 6$). Arguments of $\left(\sqrt[6]{z}\right)^4$ are
$$0, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{8\pi}{3}, 4\pi, \frac{16\pi}{3}, \frac{20\pi}{3}$$
and number of unique values = $\frac{6}{\gcd(6, 4)} = 3$, because $0 = 4\pi, \frac{4\pi}{3} = \frac{16\pi}{3}, \frac{8\pi}{3} = \frac{20\pi}{3}$ are the same points on unit circle (see figure).
[points on unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnRyb.png)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval, Could you please tell me what I did wrong? =(( Do you need any clarification? This is just my first question.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have updated the question. Open it please

Comment: Fixed error in the last example.